# Text after nested bullets not aligned

Tags: align, enumerate, enumitem

[image]

As shown in the picture, the text after the (a), (b), (c) column are all not aligned on their left.

The code used is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=8.775mm, noitemsep, align=left, nolistsep] 
    \item[\textbf{1}]
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=6.19mm, noitemsep, align=left]
        \item[\textbf{(a)}]
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5.525mm, noitemsep]
            \item[\textbf{(i)}]
            \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=6.43mm, noitemsep, align=left]
                \item[\textbf{(a)}] Text Here
                \item[\textbf{(b)}] Text Here
                \item[\textbf{(c)}] Text Here
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How do I make the text align? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `left = <labelindent> .. <leftmargin>` to set two align points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=8.775mm, noitemsep, align=left, nolistsep] 
    \item[\textbf{1}]
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=6.19mm, noitemsep, align=left]
        \item[\textbf{(a)}]
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5.525mm, noitemsep]
            \item[\textbf{(i)}]
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},left=0mm .. 6.43mm, noitemsep, align=left]
                \item Text Here
                \item Text Here
                \item Text Here
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: It's better to set the label by using the optional argument of the environment, not the `item`s.

Comment: What if I do not want to use `label=\textbf{(\alph*)}`?

I also insist on using `leftmargin=6.43mm`.

Comment: See the edited answer. The way of setting labels is not mandatory and you can do as you like.

Comment: Correct me if I did something wrong, but the code seems dependent of this specific method of setting labels you suggested. The problem reappears when I remove `label=\textbf{(\alph*)}` and set the labels manually.

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification -- "Correct me if something is wrong" -- If you don't want to number/label the list items in an automated way and instead prefer to "set the labels manually", you probably shouldn't be using an `enumerate` environment to begin with. Instead, do look into using a `description` environment.

Comment: @Mico Valid point - surely a lesson learnt on my part. However, I am still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: @EnergeticElectrification - You appear to have made an unwarranted distinction between a suggested approach -- setting the option `left=0mm .. 6.43mm`as part of an autoamtic numbering system -- and being able to override this approach manually. For sure, if you set `\begin{enumerate}[...,left=0mm .. 6.43mm,...,align=left]` up front, there's absolutely no reason why you couldn't also write `\item[\textbf{(e)}] Text Here ... \item[\textbf{(i)}] ... Text Here \item[\textbf{(X)}] Text Here` later on.

Comment: @Mico I did not realise that, my apologies. Thanks.